# Use Sinatra's action as method

Tags: ruby, routes, sinatra

I want to call a Sinatra action as a method. For example, I have defined

```
get '/' do
  puts "hi"
end
```

I want to call the above as a method but not as an action. How to achieve this?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Comment: Read http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Triggering%20Another%20Route.